# How can I make JetBrains Intellij IDEA 13 recognize a Git imported project as a Maven project?

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, intellij-13

I have been having trouble with IDEA (`JetBrains Intellij IDEA 13`) not reading the `pom.xml` file after the project has been imported using the `VCS`. How can I make IDEA recognize this as a `Maven project` so it gets all the dependencies from the `pom.xml`?

This is what the `pom.xml` currently looks like in `Project View`:

[image]

Comment: can you try reimporting the checked project using the steps mentioned in 
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-project-from-maven-model.html#2

Comment: How would that work out with Git?

Comment: right click the project, you will see Git as option as item..
See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-git-integration.html for details

Comment: But how can it be imported from Git as a Maven Project? I do not use the Git Command Line much and don't know about it.

Comment: If your pom is correct and on the correct path then Intellij will recognize is and ask you to import this project

Comment: @zpontikas The pom.xml is in the correct path and has no errors, but it has not done so.

Comment: Show us project's file/path structure and the place that pom.xml is

Comment: @zpontikas http://imgur.com/dnEndgK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How can I fix this?**

1. Right click the pom.xml file.
2. In the menu select "`Add as Maven project`", the project will now
   turn into a Maven project and the pom.xml file icon should turn into an `m`, the `Maven` logo.

**How did it occur?**

This occurs when you don't include the "`.idea`" folder in the `Git` repository.

Comment: No this is not the reason that this problem occurs and it is considered bad practice to add the IDE folder/files to the CVS. This is why you have Maven so that you can import the projects in any IDE without having to add the project files in your version control

Comment: You can also drag and drop the file to the Maven tab to add the project settings

Answer (score 2):

To test it try this our:

1. Go to VCS->Chech out from Version Control->Git
2. Enter this spring project:https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase
3. Select the desired clone path and press "Clone"

If everything is working correctly it will ask you to create an Intellij project

Comment: It did work well for that one. When I VCS -> Check out from Version Control -> Git from my project I always have to manually add the module because it doesnt recognize it for some reason.

Comment: Ok I see what the problem is.

Comment: Ok I see what the problem is. Move everything to your root folder. You have have your project in the "PrimeFactions" folder. If you move it you your root folder it will work